# safest way of sending username + password when $_GET is my only option

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post, get

I'm making a game and I can only request pages. eg.(login.php?username=myuser&password=mypass)

The game can recieve the results from a php too.

At the moment the password is encrypted. What's the best way of achieving a safe method of logging in?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use SSL. That will encrypt the password over the wire.

Don't send the raw password, either. Hash it and send the hash.

That's still not going to give you great security because the hashed password will still be in the browser history and could be used for a replay attack. You can mitigate this by using a challenge-response mechanism. Get the server to include a large random sequence of bytes (a nonce) along with the login page, then the client can XOR the password hash with this nonce and send the result. The server can apply the same XOR to obtain the original hash.

SSL will prevent eavesdropping, sending the hash will make things a little harder for a casual attacker, and the nonce will prevent replay. That's probably not a complete list of things to look out for, but it's a start.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to comment? I'd like to know why you think that using SSL is a bad idea.

Comment: thanks for the great response! I'll be getting a ssl certificate asap